# How can I get wifi-menu to display asterisks instead of plaintext passwords?

Tags: arch-linux, security, wifi

By default, using `wifi-menu` to authenticate on a network shows the password *in plain text* as it's being entered. Is there any way to use asterisks instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-o` option.

```
wifi-menu -o
```

---

```
wifi-menu -h

[...]
      -o, --obscure  Show asterisks for the characters of the password
                     and store the password as a hexadecimal string
```

Comment: This is just as good. Is there any way to have this on by default (outside of setting a shell alias)?

Comment: I don't know about that. I have an alias for it: `alias wm='sudo wifi-menu -o'`. I also have this: `%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/wifi-menu` in my `sudoers` file so I don't have to type my password every time I use `wifi-menu`.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about having my `sudo` password visible, that's normally concealed by the default askpass program anyway.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's concealed. This is just a personal preference. I figure that if you are in the sudoers group, you shouldn't need to type a password for connecting to a network!